# Remove n number of characters from unknown length of string

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I have the following code that removes 5 characters onwards from a string of unknown length.

```
string latitudelength       = latitude.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //<<--Get length of string
int intLatitudeLength       = Convert.ToInt32(latitudelength) -5; //<--Now substract 5 char from it
string trimLatitude         = latitude.Remove(5, intLatitudeLength); //<-- now remove all chars after 5th
```

The above just seems a long way round just to trim a string of unknown length to 5 characters.

Is there a more professional way?

### Thanks

Could someone explain why this post was marked down, a lot off examples posted here use substring, if the length of the string is known then substring would be OK, but the length of the string is not known, so substring could not be used.

My example calculates the length of the string, and then removes the required number of characters.

My question clearly asks if there is a more professional way.

---

I have cleaned my code up, so hopefully it can help anyone in the future

```
string latitudelength       = latitude.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int intLatitudeLength       = Convert.ToInt32(latitudelength);
string trimLatitude         = intLatitudeLength > 5 ? latitude.Substring(0,5) : latitude;
```

It now checks the length of the string, if longer than 5 chars use substring, if less just display latitude etc. I have not added the code for if the string is null

Comment: why not `latitude.SubString(0, 5);`?

Comment: I'm very curious as to why you're converting `latitude`'s length to a string then back to an int.

Comment: Hi Cuong Le what would happen if the string was only 4 characters, it would throw an error

Comment: Hi Eric, because that was the only way I could add intLatitudeLength to trimLatitude without it causing an error

Comment: You are right, I add new answer using `Take`

Answer (score 6):

```
string trimLatitude = latitude.Substring(0, Math.Min(latitude.Length,5));
```

Comment: `trimLatitude.Length < 5`

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep Edit made :)

Answer (score 2):

Why you are calling `.ToString()` on the `Length` property and then converting it to an int? That's an uncessary operation.

You could just do:

```
 string trimLatitude = latitude.substring(0, intLatitudeLength);
```

Also since you state trim.  I hope you are not just trying to trim `5 whitespace characters`.  Otherwise you could just use `.Trim()`

Comment: Hi Darren sorry wrong choice of words

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson - no problem, I was just trying to explain that `.Trim()` is better suited for stripping white space directly.

Answer (score 1):

[string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.substring.aspx) can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid exception from `SubString`, you can use LINQ:

```
 trimLatitude  = new string(latitude.Take(5).ToArray());
```